# Solve iteration algorithm in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, iteration

So this is hurting my head, I am not very good with programming obviously. I have,

```
LetterArray = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
NumArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
ListOfLetters = []
```

and I want to take an element from `NumArray` and, starting on `LetterArray[0]`, go up var `x` amount of times in LetterArray, and add that element (say var `y` to the array. Then starting on `y` go up the next number in `NumArray`, and so on. Then print the `ListOfLetters` to console.

My goal is for the output to be like this: `[a, c, f, c, a, f, e, e, f, a]`.

I am drawing a blank on how to go about this in code.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want, could you explain it better?

Comment: Looks like a job/ interview quiz. Interesting question though. Please post all details.

Comment: You probably want to do something with [Array#slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice).

Comment: Nah i just made it up while i was playing guitar...decided i wanted to use the fib sequence to generate a sequence of notes in E mixolydian...

Comment: For one, that isn't an array of letters, it's an array of references that are the variables `a` through `g`. You probably want strings and thus need to quote them (e.g. `"a"`).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (if I get your requirements right of course)?

```
letter_array = %w[a b c d e f g]
number_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
list_of_letters = []

number_array.inject(0) do |offset, delta| 
  list_of_letters << letter_array[offset] 
  (offset + delta) % letter_array.size
end

p list_of_letters #=> ["a", "b", "d", "g", "d", "b", "a", "a", "b", "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Either I don't understand your problem description, or the example output you showed is wrong from a certain point onwards. Anyway, maybe this gets you started:

```
letter_array = [*?a..?g]
number_array = *1..10
list_of_letters = []

number_array.inject(0) do |s, n| 
  i = s + n
  list_of_letters << letter_array[i % letter_array.size - 1] 
  i 
end
```

This produces the output `["a", "c", "f", "c", "a", "g", "g", "a", "c", "f"]`.

Alternatively you can also first create the indices and then use them (this doesn't require a pre-initialized `list_of_letters`):

```
indices = number_array.inject([]) { |a, n| a << (a.last || 0) + n ; a})
list_of_letters = indices.map { |i| letter_array[i%letter_array.size-1] }
```

Comment: I think my example output is wrong. But

letter_array = ['E', 'F#', 'G#','A', 'B', 'C#', 'D']
number_array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597]
list_of_letters = []

number_array.inject(0) do |s, n| 
  i = s + n
  list_of_letters << letter_array[i % letter_array.size - 1] 
  i 
end
p list_of_letters

is what i was going for...though, the output gives me ["E", "F#", "A", "D", "B", "C#", "B", "B", "A", "G#", "E", "B", "D", "C#", "D", "D", "E"]

Comment: but when I hand count it, I got E, F#, G#, B, E, B, B....etc.
I want to start on E, go up 1 to F#, then go up 1 to G#, then up 2, to B....i hope this makes this more clear?

Answer (score 0):

```
ar = ('a'..'g').to_a.cycle #keeps on cycling 
res = []
p 10.times.map do |n|
  n.times{ar.next} #cycle one time too short (the first time n is 0)
  res << ar.next #cycle once more and store
end
p res #=>["a", "c", "f", "c", "a", "g", "g", "a", "c", "f"]
```